# Are there languages without separate words for man and woman, just a generic term for both?

Tags: list-of-languages, nouns

I am not talking about how in some languages, e.g. English, "man" is the more generic term, but languages where there is no separate word for "man" or "woman" at all. I am curious if there are any languages that lack this distinction. Maybe they just have a generic word for "human".

Comment: There are languages where the generic word for "human" is the more common one, but I don't know of any that don't have separate words for "man" and "woman" at all.

Comment: In Old English woman was called "wif man", which meant "female person".